# How to set credentials to use Gmail API from GCE VM Command Line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I'm trying to enable my Linux VM on GCE to access my Gmail account in order to send emails.

I've found this article, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python, which reads some Gmail account information (it's useful since I just want to test my connection).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, I'm not sure which Credentials I need to set, as when I set and use:

1. **Service Account**: I receive the following message `ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.`
2. **OAuth client ID for Web Application type**: the code runs well, however I receive the following message when trying to first authorize the application's access:

> Erro 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:60443/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D)

3. **OAuth client ID for Desktop type**: the code runs well, however I receive the following message when trying to first authorize the application's access:

> localhost connection has been refused

Does anyone know how is the correct setup and if I'm missing anything?

Thanks

---

**[Nov17th]**

After adding the gmail scope to my VM's scopes I ran the python script and I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart2.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart2.py", line 18, in main
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId="107628233971924038182").execute()
  File "/home/lucasnunesfe9/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lucasnunesfe9/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/107628233971924038182/labels?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">
```

I checked the error HTTP link and it shows:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Is any manual procedure needed in a "first authorization step"?

*PS: reinforcing that I have already enabled my Service Account to "G Suite Domain-wide Delegation". This action generated an OAuth 2.0 Client ID, which is being used in the python script (variable userId).*

Comment: Have a try with the [Google-auth library](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/index.html). Use the default credential mode [(ADC)](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default) -> `credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()`. Think to scope correctly your Compute Engine. If you have issues, add more detail in your question and I will provide you an full answer

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, i'm not sure if your suggestion would fit in the script (I've added it to my question). See that this piece of code: 

"flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)"

...asks for a file path, comprising the client secrets. Additionally, it's been informed that this script is applicable as "The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command-line application". So, it seems odd that I'm struggling to do so in a VM. Just to reinforce, this VM is instantiated in Google Cloud Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I never understood this example. I think it's too old (and even compliant Python 2.6!!)

Anyway, you can forget the first part and get a credential like this

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():

    creds, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, because you will use a service account to access to your GMAIL account, you have to change the userId with the ID that you want and to grand access from the GSuite admin console to the service account to have access to GMAIL API.

---

To achieve this, you need to grant the scope of your VM service account. Stop the VM, run this (long) command, and start your VM again. The command:

- Takes the current scopes of your VM (and clean/format them)
- Add the gmail scope
- Set the scope to the VM (it's a BETA command)

```
gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes <YOUR_VM_NAME> --zone <YOUR_VM_ZONE> \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly,\
$(gcloud compute instances describe <YOUR_VM_NAME> --zone <YOUR_VM_ZONE> \
--format json | jq -c ".serviceAccounts[0].scopes" | sed -E "s/\[(.*)\]/\1/g" | sed -E "s/\"//g")
```

Comment: Hi @guillaume, I tried your suggested script and also I've enabled my service account to have the G Suite Domain-wide Delegation access (and I used my userID in the script). However, I received the following message:
`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/107628233971924038182/labels?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`. I couldn't see my tocken.pickle file in the current directory. Would you know this could help us to understand what is going on?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, the SCOPE of your Compute Engine service account is important. I updated my answer with a command that do it. Change your VM name and zone.

Comment: I updated your answer with my analysis/results... unfortunately, it's still not working

Comment: Correct, the double quotes broke the command. I updated the script. However, I could accept your edit because the scope that you propose wasn't correct, and you loose all the scopes of your current VM. Let me know if it's better now.

Comment: your script is ok now (it appends the gmail scope to the VM's list of scope). however, I still receive a HttpError, it's different from the first one (`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/107628233971924038182/labels?alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.">`). I updated my original question with further information